# Nodejs: Call a lot of time the same function 100% CPU

Tags: node.js

i've made a simple program in nodejs that simulate a card solitaire game.
Now i want try to execute this a lot of times and take all the wins and lose and get a statistics of that.
So i put the main program in a function (obviously i put outside of this function all the global variable and inside all the local variable) and i use process.nextTick(solitaire); at the end of solitaire function for call it infinite times, but my CPU go to 100%.

How i can decrease this CPU load?
Is possible call my solitaire function 1000 times, all async, wait that all have end and re-call them for make it faster?

Thanks in advice and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run some calculations, and by default any programming language will run them as quickly as it can.  You should not be surprised that your CPU utilization goes to 100% while your program runs.  If you want to slow it down, you can do this instead:

```
setTimeout(solitaire, 100);
```

Then it will insert a brief pause between each iteration.

Comment: i find a better solution: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/
Thanks anyway :)